# cin.fail while loop input Re-Entry

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

Just trying to check that the input is a boolean variable (1 or 0) for this problem.

However, whenever the while loop is triggered, (i.e. by not entering a 1 or 0), it just falls through and says that the condition is true.

I would like for the user to be able to re-enter their input after an incorrect input. How would I go about doing this?

***My code:***

```
int main() {
bool a,b,c;
    cout << "This program will determine the value of the condition !(a||b) && c " << endl;
    cout << "Please enter boolean values for a, b, and c. (0=F, 1=T) ";

    cin >> a;
        while (cin.fail())
        {
        cin.ignore(1000,'|n');
        cin.clear();
        cout << "Error: Enter only 0 or 1" << endl;
        cout << "Enter in a new value for a" << endl;
        }
    cin >> b;
    cin >> c;
    cout << "The condition !(xx||xx)&&xx ";
    if(!(a||b) && c)
    {
        cout << "is true";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "is false";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `cin >> a;` in at the end of your while loop.

`cin.clear()` will remove the error and then the while loop will stop.

Like so:

```
cin >> a;
while (cin.fail())
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
    cout << "Error: Enter only 0 or 1" << endl;
    cout << "Enter in a new value for a" << endl;
    cin >> a;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But, if I input a letter, why does it repeat the two outputs endlessly in my console? Is there a simple way to fix that?

Comment: @kpnd: there was typo in your question and this answer's newline char literal - it should be `'\n'` not `'|n'`... better fix and try again.

Comment: @TonyD thanks for the check. However, my problem with the endless loop when inputting non-numbers still persists. Any ideas?

Comment: @kpnd: you are applying a similar `while` loop to the other two booleans, aren't you?

Comment: You should use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` instead of `1000`. The latter has no advantage while the former has a special meaning for `std::istream::ignore` and does exactly what you want here.

Comment: @TonyD yeah exactly. I just added similar code below each of the other cin inputs.

Comment: @kpnd: oh - noticed another error in this answer - need to `clear();` before doing the `ignore`, otherwise the latter's... well... ignored.

Comment: Thanks TonyD and kpnd for improving the answer while I was AFK.